# alignment disturbs while converting html to pdf using mPDF in php

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I am trying to convert HTML to PDF using mPDF but alignment disturbs while doing this.

My HTML generates for this using

```
highlight_string($html);
```

is like below:

```
    "<body style="height:11in;width:8.5in;">
<table style='margin-left:0.25in;margin-right:0.25in;margin-bottom:in;margin-top:1in;'>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="background:#9abdd6;margin-left:0.25in;margin-right:0.25in;margin-bottom:in;margin-top:1in; height:3in;width:4in; position: relative;  float:left; ">
<div style="height:3in; width:4in;background:#9abdd6">
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:99px;background:;top:204px;width:auto;height:auto;color:gray;scaleX:0.51px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:;font-weight:;font-family:;text-align:">
<div style="left:99px;top:204px;width:196.86px;height:40px;background-color:gray">
</div>
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:131px;background:;top:215px;width:auto;height:auto;color:black;scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;font-family:Times New Roman;text-align:center">
Darshan</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:149px;background:;top:105px;width:auto;height:auto;color:rgb(0,0,0);scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:;font-weight:;font-family:;text-align:">
<img src="http://192.168.1.51/mleads9.6/user_files/1403762976/sponsor/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:316px;background:;top:206px;width:auto;height:auto;color:black;scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;font-family:Times New Roman;text-align:center">
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div style="background:#9abdd6;margin-left:0.25in;margin-right:0.25in;margin-bottom:in;margin-top:1in; height:3in;width:4in; position: relative;  float:left; ">
<div style="height:3in; width:4in;background:#9abdd6">
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:99px;background:;top:204px;width:auto;height:auto;color:gray;scaleX:0.51px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:;font-weight:;font-family:;text-align:">
<div style="left:99px;top:204px;width:196.86px;height:40px;background-color:gray">
</div>
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:131px;background:;top:215px;width:auto;height:auto;color:black;scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;font-family:Times New Roman;text-align:center">
Trainee</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:149px;background:;top:105px;width:auto;height:auto;color:rgb(0,0,0);scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:;font-weight:;font-family:;text-align:">
<img src="http://192.168.1.51/mleads9.6/user_files/1403762976/sponsor/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:316px;background:;top:206px;width:auto;height:auto;color:black;scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;font-family:Times New Roman;text-align:center">
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div style="background:#9abdd6;margin-left:0.25in;margin-right:0.25in;margin-bottom:in;margin-top:1in; height:3in;width:4in; position: relative;  float:left; ">
<div style="height:3in; width:4in;background:#9abdd6">
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:99px;background:;top:204px;width:auto;height:auto;color:gray;scaleX:0.51px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:;font-weight:;font-family:;text-align:">
<div style="left:99px;top:204px;width:196.86px;height:40px;background-color:gray">
</div>
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:131px;background:;top:215px;width:auto;height:auto;color:black;scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;font-family:Times New Roman;text-align:center">
Darshan</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:149px;background:;top:105px;width:auto;height:auto;color:rgb(0,0,0);scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:;font-weight:;font-family:;text-align:">
<img src="http://192.168.1.51/mleads9.6/user_files/1403762976/sponsor/Chrysanthemum.jpg" width="100" height="100"/>
</div>
<div style ="position:absolute;float:left;left:316px;background:;top:206px;width:auto;height:auto;color:black;scaleX:1px;scaleY:1px;opacity:1px;font-size:20px;font-weight:normal;font-family:Times New Roman;text-align:center">
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>"
```

which shows perfect HTML result...

The code I am using is:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->allow_output_buffering = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

but when I convert it to PDF then alignment totally disturbs.

Answer (score 0):

mPDF doesn't support "float" well.
The alternative method is to use nesting tables.
I suggest that you use only the table tags as much as possible, and do not use div or span.

Answer (score -2):

mPDF does not support floating inside tables.

See [Manual page on CSS Support](https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html)

Comment: Can you post some content from the link?

Comment: Why would I do that? It basically says the same as my first sentence, but it comes from an authority.

Comment: One reason why you would do that is that links sometimes break, which could make your answer somewhat redundant.

Comment: The answer is "mPDF does not support floating inside tables.". Which is contained in the answer itself and in the link. I guess that some content from the link is posted, then, and the answer would not be redundant if the link is broken.

Comment: The mPDF website has since been closed since you added it, I looked there is no replacement, so by failing to copy the jist, what you've left here is a dead artifact on Stackoverflow, which harms stackoverflow requiring someone like me to come clean up after you.